# Table Separator

Tags: tables, tabularx

i'm trying to make create this table using tabularx but for some reason the separator won't show up.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{small}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { 
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X |
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X |
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X |
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
            >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
        }
        \toprule\
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{1,B}$= 304,15K }& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{1,D}$= 306,15K} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{1,S}$= 301,15K}\\ 
        & $EER_{real,min,B}$  [-]& $c_{gesamt,min}$ [€/kW]&$EER_{real,min,D}$ [-]& $c_{gesamt,min}$ [€/kW] & $EER_{real,min,S}$ [-] & $c_{gesamt,min}$ [€/kW]\\ 
        \midrule
        $t_{1}-1K$     &    2,93 & 1181    & 3,54 & 1878,96 & 5,23 & 1588,32\\
        $t_{1}$       & 2,80 & 1255,59 & 3,38 & 1969,74 & 4,95 & 1722,10\\
        $t_{1}+1K$     & 2,69 & 1326,91 & 3,25 & 2057,17 & 4,56 & 1847,59\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{small}
\caption{Verschiebung der minimalen Punkt der Gesamtkosten (Index: \textbf{B}erlin, \textbf{D}ubai, \textbf{S}urabaya)}
\label{tab:EERreal_Verschiebung}
```

\end{table}

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: \multicolumn@{2}{c|}{...} should work. Apart from that, please be aware that the horizontal lines Form the booktabs package were designed to be used in tables without vertical lines, hence the small gaps around the intersections.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend that you (a) *omit* all vertical lines and (b) switch from a `tabularx` to a `tabular*` environment. I would also suggest distinguishing more systematically between material that belongs in caption and material that belongs in a legend.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\small
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth} {@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            l *{6}{c} }
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{1,B}={}$304,15K}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{1,D}={}$306,15K} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{1,S}={}$301,15K}\\ 
        \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7}
        & $EER_{\mathrm{real,min},B}$ & $c_{\mathrm{ges.,min}}$  &
          $EER_{\mathrm{real,min},D}$ & $c_{\mathrm{ges.,min}}$  &
          $EER_{\mathrm{real,min},S}$ & $c_{\mathrm{ges.,min}}$ \\ {}
        & [--] & [€/kW] & [--] & [€/kW] & [--] & [€/kW] \\
        \midrule
        $t_{1}-1K$ & 2,93 & 1181\phantom{,00} & 3,54 & 1878,96 & 5,23 & 1588,32\\
        $t_{1}$    & 2,80 & 1255,59 & 3,38 & 1969,74 & 4,95 & 1722,10\\
        $t_{1}+1K$ & 2,69 & 1326,91 & 3,25 & 2057,17 & 4,56 & 1847,59\\
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Index: \textbf{B}erlin, \textbf{D}ubai, \textbf{S}urabaya} 
    \end{tabular*}
\caption{Verschiebung der minimalen Punkte der Gesamtkosten}
\label{tab:EERreal_Verschiebung}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to change is inside your `multicolumn`s:

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$t_{1,B}$= 304,15K }& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$t_{1,D}$= 306,15K} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{1,S}$= 301,15K}
```

You need to repeat that you want to have the horizontal rule.

NOTE: Type the vertical bar only once, so do not type `|c|` because this will look odd (like you have double line width).

---

If you are interested in some additional improvements:

- Usually you write non-mathematical indices upright, that's why I would say `EER_{\mathrm{real, min, B}}` or `EER_{\mathrm{real}, \mathrm{min}, \mathrm{B}}` (assuming that 'B' is a non-mathematic index). Everything you can spell out to a 'natrual language word', like 'real', 'min', 'gesamt' I would write upright, everything else (like `x_i`, the i-th component of a vector) I'd leave in normal math mode.
- As leandriis said, the `booktabs` package is designed for tabulars without vertical lines as the author doesn't like them at all.

Answer (score 2):

Small variant of @Mico answer. By use of the `makcell` and `siunitx` package, defined new math operators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\real}{real}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ges}{ges}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4,
         output-decimal-marker={,}}         
    \small
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth} {@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                >{$}l<{$} *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=4.2]} 
                             }
    \toprule
    & \mcc[2]{$t_{1,\mathrm{B}} = \qty{304,15}{K}$}
        & \mcc[2]{$t_{1,\mathrm{D}} = \qty{306,15}{K}$}
            & \mcc[2]{$t_{1,\mathrm{S}}= \qty{301,15}{K}$}\\
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7}
    & {\makecell{$EER_{\real,\min,\mathrm{B}}$\\ {[-]}}}    
        & {\makecell{$c_{\ges.,\min}$\\ {[€/kW]}}}  
            & {\makecell{$EER_{\real,\min,\mathrm{D}}$\\ {[-]}}}     
                & {\makecell{$c_{\ges.,\min}$\\ {[€/kW]}}} 
                    & {\makecell{$EER_{\real,\min,\mathrm{S}}$\\ {[-]}}}     
                        & {\makecell{$c_{\ges.,\min}$\\ {[€/kW]}}}          \\
    \midrule
t_{1}-\qty{1}{K}   
    & 2,93 & 1181    & 3,54 & 1878,96 & 5,23 & 1588,32\\
 t_{1}          
    & 2,80 & 1255,59 & 3,38 & 1969,74 & 4,95 & 1722,10\\
 t_{1}+\qty{1}{K}
    & 2,69 & 1326,91 & 3,25 & 2057,17 & 4,56 & 1847,59\\
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Index: \textbf{B}erlin, \textbf{D}ubai, \textbf{S}urabaya}
    \end{tabular*}
\caption{Verschiebung der minimalen Punkte der Gesamtkosten}
\label{tab:EERreal_Verschiebung}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]